Why are these 2 terms canceled out in the ELBO derivation for diffusion models?
I was looking at the derivation of the ELBO for diffusion models from this website and I'm a little bit confused as to why they cancelled these two terms out.


Where you see this derivation in your linked website? which equation number?

37 in the show me the proof part

Indeed this sounds very confusing until you expand the product $\Pi$ terms as outlined below:
$$\frac{p_{\theta}(x_1|x_2)q(x_1|x_0)p_{\theta}(x_2|x_3)q(x_2|x_0)...p_{\theta}(x_{T-1}|x_T)q(x_{T-1}|x_0)}{q(x_1|x_2,x_0)q(x_2|x_0)...q(x_{T-2}|x_{T-1},x_0)q(x_{T-1}|x_0)q(x_{T-1}|x_T,x_0)q(x_T|x_0)}$$
Therefore now it's obvious that the cancelation is from all alternating $q$ terms with only one conditioned variable $x_0$  in the numerator and denominator, respectively, except the first and last terms $\frac{q(x_1|x_0)}{q(x_T|x_0)}$ still remain. That's why in your reference the next step in show me proof section there appears one additional middle term $+\log \frac{q(x_1|x_0)}{q(x_T|x_0)}$. The author perhaps should expand like here to help reader's clear comprehension considering he's already written so many detailed steps.
